# Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Compute

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm dx$$

Comment: wolfram gives the answer as 0.272198

Comment: Mathematica gives the answer $\frac{\pi}{8} \log 2$. But I do not know how it computed this number...

Comment: @Chris: Even, i thought of that only :)

Comment: Why dont you try and solve these Integrals yourself. Browsing through your most recent questions, you have had this type of question almost exclusively. Other users get downvoted for this. I see no reason not to hint the same to you and at least show some effort. -1

Comment: @CBenni: are you sure you saw all my questions? How about this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299801/evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-left1-frac-ln-xfx-right-displaystyle-frac or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289172/compute-lim-s-to-0-left-int-01-gamma-xs-space-mathrmdx-right1

Comment: This is 2005 Putnam A5.http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=2&cid=23&year=2005]AoPS

Comment: Why don't you try to show some of your work....

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Put $x = \tan\theta$, then your integral transforms to $$I= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log(1+\tan\theta) \ d\theta. \tag{1}$$

Now using the property that $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) \ dx,$$ we have $$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log\biggl(1+\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta\Bigr)\biggr) \ d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log\biggl(\frac{2}{1+\tan\theta} \biggr) \ d\theta.\tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$2I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log(2) \ d\theta\Rightarrow I= \log(2) \cdot \frac{\pi}{8}.$$

Answer (score 68):

Consider:
$$I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+ax)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$
than, the derivative $I'$ is equal:
$$I'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+ax)(1+x^2)} \, dx = \frac{2 a \arctan x - 2\ln (1+a x) + \ln (1+x^2)}{2(1+a^2)} \Big|_0^1\\
= \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} - \frac{\ln (1+a)}{1+a^2}$$
Hence:
$$I(1) = \int_0^1 \left(  \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} - \frac{\ln (1+a)}{1+a^2} \right) \, da \\
2 I(1) = \int_0^1 \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} \, da = \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2$$
Divide both sides by $2$ and you're done.

Comment: Yes. It's very excellent and different method.

Comment: Thanks, but it needs much more calculations than the soulution proposed by @Chandrasekhar :)

Comment: @qoqosz Nice way of seeing how differentiation under the integral sign works. Thanks +1.

Comment: @Mark Hurd: right.

Comment: @qoqosz Can you please explain how you went from $I'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+ax)(1+x^2)} \, dx$ to $\frac{2 a \arctan x - 2\ln (1+a x) + \ln (1+x^2)}{2(1+a^2)} \Big|_0^1$?

Comment: @Astrobleme in case you are still wondering, it is partial fractions!

Answer (score 56):

Good evening,
I've got another method by putting $x=(1-t)/(1+t)$, we obtain 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x^2+1}dx=\int_1^0\frac{\ln\frac{2}{1+t}}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2+1}\cdot\left\{-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\right\}dt =\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2-\ln (1+t)}{t^2+1}\ dt.$$
You can finish easily.

Comment: That substitution is very powerful, and used it when I met ugly integrals. I didn't use it here (unfortunately). Great solution! (+1)

Comment: How is the last expression any easier to computre than what we started with ?

Comment: @CivilSigma, if you look at the first and last expressions, you see you have an equation of the form $A=B-A$, where $A$ is the integral you're trying to evaluate and $B$ is an integral that's easy to evaluate.

Comment: Great solution (+1) but how does one even think of that substitution in such situation? I mean, this is a clearly a "let's try it out and hope it works method". The accepted solution is more straightforward.

Answer (score 41):

If $(1+x)(1+y)=2$, then
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\\
1+x^2&=2\frac{1+y^2}{(1+y)^2}\\
\frac{1+x^2}{1+x}&=\frac{1+y^2}{1+y}
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$
and since $(1+y)\,\mathrm{d}x+(1+x)\,\mathrm{d}y=0$ we get
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)-\log(1+y)}{1+y^2}\mathrm{d}y\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Adding the left side to both sides and dividing by $2$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)}{1+y^2}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac\pi8\log(2)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I excuse Mr robjohn. I did'nt see your answer.

Comment: I love your answers!

Comment: $(1+x)(1+y)=2$ mysteriously  appears in the beginning. Did you do reverse-engineering?

Comment: Actually, I have used $(1+x)(1+y)=2$ many times. It means that $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)=\frac\pi4$ and so, is useful to try in situations with $\frac1{1+x^2}$ in the denominator. The arctangent relation leads immediately to $(2)$.

Answer (score 25):

Start with $$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(1+\tan x)dx &= \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\sin x+\cos x)dx - \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos x)dx \\
 &= \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln\left(\cos(x-\frac{\pi}4)\right)dx +\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\sqrt 2)dx - \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos x)dx.
\end{align*}$$ Now change $\pi/4-x=t$ in the first integral: $$=\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos t) dt +\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\sqrt 2)dx - \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos x)dx$$ and the result follows. Changing $x=\tan u$ in the first integral yields your integral. As far as I know these are said Bertrand's integrals.

@Chandrasehkar: see here http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

Comment: @Unoqualunque: The link was really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 15):

Let us consider $$A=\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{x}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}dx dy$$
By Fubini's theorem, we have : $$A=\int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\int_0^1\frac{x\,dy}{1+xy}\right]dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$ and$$A=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}dx\right]dy$$But$$\frac{x}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+y^2}\left(\frac{-y}{1+xy}+\frac{x+y}{1+x^2}\right)$$and therefore$$A=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+y^2}\left(-\ln(1+y)+\frac{\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{\pi y}{y}\right)dy=-A+\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{4}$$Finally :$$\boxed{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{8}}$$

Comment: How did you see this magical decomposition: $\frac{x}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+y^2} \left( \frac{-y}{1+xy} + \frac{x+y}{1+x^2} \right)$ ?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal : it is merely a partial fraction decomposition in the real domain (where the main variable is considered to be $x$). No magic at all in it ;-)
The interesting part is that this transformation leads to an explicit calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Note
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x^2+1}dx
=\int_0^1\underset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{\frac{\ln \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x^2+1}}dx
 + \int_0^1\frac{\ln \sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}dx\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{\ln \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x^2+1}dx
 + \int_0^1\frac{\ln \sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{\ln2}2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac\pi8\ln2
\end{align}

Comment: This is the same method posted by both @boulid and Robert Johnson more than 7 years before your post herein.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the residue theory to calculate
$$J=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln|1+x|}{(1+x^2)} \, dx $$
by putting 
$$f(z)=\frac{\ln(1+z)}{(1+z^2)}$$ and we obtain 
$$J = 2\pi i\frac{\ln(1+i)}{(i+i)}=\pi\ln\left(\sqrt2e^{\frac14\pi i}\right)=\pi\left(\frac12\ln2+\frac14\pi i\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+\frac{\pi^2i}4$$

$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx 
+\int_{-1}^0 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx 
+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx 
+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$

Then by putting $(t-1)e^{\pi i}=1+x$ in the first integral we obtain:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\pi i+\ln(t-1)}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{\pi^2i}4+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t-1)}{t^2+1}dt$$

Then by putting $t=-x$ in the second integral we obtain:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2-1)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}2\ln2$$

then by putting $t=1/x$ in the second integral we obtain:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}4\ln2$$

and we put $x=(1-t)/(1+t)$ in the first integral 
we obtain after calculus :
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \, (1+x)}{1+x^2}= \frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2$$

Comment: It's almost impossible to read this. You should find and read an introduction to MathJax, like [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In posting an Answer to a (by now four year old) Question having already an Accepted Answer, it is helpful to your Readers to highlight what new information you provide.

Comment: why it's impossible ? 

Comment: @Michel I mean, compared to the accepted answer, which one is much easier to read? Also, you spelled "residue" wrong.

Comment: @mjw I was curious about how this was working as well :)

Comment: @user5713492,  Thanks for taking on editing/LaTeXing/MathJaxing this!  Now we'll have to look at it and see if it's got everything ...

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but there is a branch point at $z=-1$, so we need to handle that as well by defining the branch cut and integrating along a small semicircle around this point.

Comment: @mjw Yeah, I was careful about that branch point and my little semicircle ran above it. That's why the phase of the logarithm was $e^{\pi i/4}$ at $x=i$ and $e^{\pi i}$ on the real axis for $x<-1$. AFAIK the residue theorem is incompatible with absolute value. The integral over the semicircle of radius $r$ can be bounded in magnitude by $-\pi r\ln r/(1-r^2)$ so it vanishes in the limit as $r\rightarrow\infty$. The details after $x=(1-t)/(1+t)$ are perhaps a bit unexpected in that the residue that was carefully computed at the very beginning was completely canceled out and then some!

Comment: Looks nice, but I think there are some questions:  How does $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{\ln |1+x|}{1+x^2} \, dx$ become $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{\ln (1+x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$ and then $\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln (1-x^2)}{1+x^2} \, dx$ ?

Comment: @mjw For $-1< x<0$, $0<(1+x)<1$ so the absolute value bars do nothing. Then he has $$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\end{align}$$ Where he let $x=-t$ in the first integral and $x=t$ in the second.

Comment: Yes and yes!  Thank you!