# What is $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

It's so deceptively simple and none of the usual techniques are working. Any and all insights are welcome.

Comment: WA gives an answer in terms of polylogarithms for the indefinite integral. The definite integral has a factor of $\pi$ in it, which makes me think that WA performs it with complex contour integration.

Comment: With that and the insights given to me in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430218/dogbone-contour-integral-branch-cuts-residue-at-infinity in mind, I think it might be a good idea to start with $u=1/x-1$.

Comment: $I~=~\dfrac\pi8~\ln2.$

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322229/how-to-evaluate-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-dx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $x=\tan(t)$, we obtain the integral to be
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(1+\tan(t))dt = \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\sin(t)+\cos(t))dt - \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(t))dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt2) dt + \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sin(t+\pi/4))dt - \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(t))dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt2) dt + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(t))dt - \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(t))dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt2) dt + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \log(\cos(\pi/2-t))dt - \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(t))dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt2) dt + \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t))dt - \int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(t))dt\\
& = \dfrac{\pi}8\ln(2)
\end{align}

Comment: Perhaps related to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322235).

Comment: @robjohn Yes, not surprisingly both are written by me. (The other one in my previous avatar)