# Need help with $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Can the definite integral
$$\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx$$
be evaluated using the technique of “differentiation under integral sign”. I don't want a complete solution, just the parameter would do.

PS: An alternative approach (preferably simple) would also be welcome as long as it doesn't involve contour integration.

Comment: I know that much by using Wolfram Alpha; the problem is, how would i show it?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (a^2+x^2)}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$ seems promising

Comment: Are you sure the integral is the right one? I got $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x}=-\frac{\pi^2}{48}+\frac{3}{4}\log^2 2.$$

Comment: @curious, By any chance, this meant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-mathrm-dx

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, the powers of $x$ are different.

Comment: @Arjang: Please don't make minor edits to old posts. This applies with extra force when after the edit the title is LaTeX-only. The normal search engine cannot handle LaTeX at all, so the question titles in particular should have as little LaTeX as possible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sorry that explanation is not acceptable as reasonable to a programmer, please provide explicit examples if possible.  Thank you

Comment: @Arjang: Have you EVER tried typing LaTeX-code into the on-site search box? For example all the carets and underscores are ignored. I just typed in $x^2+x$, and [the first hit](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=x%5E2%2Bx) is based on similarity with $x2^{x+1}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/not-having-pure-latex-as-titles , also rolled back to original form before my changes

Answer (score 11):

> *I don't want a complete solution, just the parameter would do.*

Try
\begin{equation}
I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+a^2x^2\right)}{1+x}\, dx
\end{equation}

> *No upvote yet? Okay...*

Differentiating w.r.t. $a$, we have
\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\int_0^1\left[\frac{2ax^2}{(1+x)\left(1+a^2x^2\right)}\right]\, dx\\
&=\frac{2a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{2a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{1+a^2x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{2a\ln2}{1+a^2}-\frac{2\arctan a}{1+a^2}+\frac{\ln\left(1+a^2\right)}{a\left(1+a^2\right)}\\
\end{align}
then integrating back
\begin{align}
I(a)&=\ln\left(1+a^2\right)\ln2-\arctan^2(a)+\int\left[\frac{\ln\left(1+a^2\right)}{a}-\underbrace{\frac{a\ln\left(1+a^2\right)}{1+a^2}}_{({\Large\color{red}{\star}})}\right]\,da\\
&=\ln\left(1+a^2\right)\ln2-\arctan^2(a)-\frac{1}{2}{\rm{Li}}\left(-a^2\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln^2\left(1+a^2\right)+C\\
\end{align}
For $({\Large\color{red}{\star}})$ we use integration by parts once by taking $u=\ln\left(1+a^2\right)$.

Now, I'm sure you can you take it from here.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1+x}\,\dd x}
=\ln^{2}\pars{2} - \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}\,{2x \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\ln^{2}\pars{2}
-2\,\color{#c00000}{\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 - \ic x}\,\dd x}
=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{\pi^{2} \over 48} + {3 \over 4}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\approx {\tt 0.1547}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{\mu \equiv {\ic \over 1 + \ic}=\half\,\pars{1 + \ic}}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 - \ic x}\,\dd x}
=\Im\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + \ic - \ic x}\,\dd x
=\Im\bracks{-\ic\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - \ic x/\pars{1 + \ic}}
\,{\ic\,\dd x \over 1 + \ic}}
\\[5mm]&=\Im\bracks{-\ic\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - \mu x}\,\mu\,\dd x}
=\Im\bracks{-\ic\int_{\mu}^{2\mu}{\ln\pars{x/\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\Im\bracks{\left.\ic\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x \over \mu}
\right\vert_{x\ =\ \mu}^{x\ =\ 2\mu}
-\ic\int_{\mu}^{2\mu}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,{1/\mu \over x/\mu}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\Im\braces{\ic\ln\pars{1 - 2\mu}\ln\pars{2} + \ic\int_{\mu}^{2\mu}\
\underbrace{\bracks{-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}}
_{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}}}}\ \,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\Re\,{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 + \ic} - \Re\,{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 + \ic \over 2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**(Edit: Just noticed that the OP specifically requested a hint instead of a complete solution. My apologies.)**

Start by integrating by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+x^2\right)}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[\ln{(1+x)}\ln{(1+x^2)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x\ln{(1+x)}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln^2{(2)}-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln{(1+x)}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln^2{(2)}-2\mathcal{J}{(1)},\\
\end{align}$$

where we've introduced the parameter $a$ by defining the function $\mathcal{J}{(a)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln{(1+ax)}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$.