# The integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac {\ln (1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2} dx? $

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

In order to produce a solution of $I$, in

[Integrating $\int_0^1\frac{x\ln (1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$ with restricted tehniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285344/integrating-int-01-fracx-ln-1x1x2dx-with-restricted-tehniques)

for a teacher's delight, I landed up in the integral
$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac {\ln (1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2} dx? $$
Here is how $J$ emeges.
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan t\ln(1+\tan t) dt$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan (\pi/4-t)\ln(1+\tan(\pi/4- t)) ~dt=
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan t} [\ln 2 -\ln(1+\tan t)]  dt =$$ $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{2-\mbox{sec}^2 t}{(1+\tan t)^2}[\ln 2-\ln(1+\tan t)]=I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4.$$
Here 
$$I_1=2 \ln 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{dt}{(1+\tan t)^2}=\ln 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{1+\cos 2t}{(1+\sin 2 t)}dt=
\ln 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}  \frac{1-\sin 2t}{(1-\sin^ 2 2t)}dt+$$ 
$$\frac{1}{2} \ln 2 ~\ln((1+\sin 2t)|_{0}^{\pi/2}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi/4}( \tan 2t- \mbox{sec} 2t)\frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{ \ln^2 2}{2} =\frac{1}{2}(\ln 2+\ln^2 2).$$
$$I_2=- \ln 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\mbox{sec}^2 t ~ dt}{(1+\tan t)^2}=- \frac{1}{2}\ln 2.$$
$$I_3=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\mbox{sec}^2 t \ln(1+\tan t) ~ dt}{(1+\tan t)^2}=\int_{0}^{\ln 2} u e^{-u} ~du=\frac{1}{2}(1-\ln 2). $$
$$I_4=-2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac {\ln (1+\tan t)}{(1+\tan t)^2} dt =-2 J.$$
So, here the question is : How to solve the $J$ integral?
The expected answer is:
$$J=\frac{3\ln^2 2}{16}-\frac{\pi^2}{192}+\frac{1-\ln 2}{4}.$$
This comes by using the value of $I$.But, here the idea is not to use it.

Comment: Maple gives the following solution $$1/4+1/4\,{\it dilog} \left( 1/2+i/2 \right) +1/4\,{\it dilog} \left( 1
/2-i/2 \right) +1/4\, \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{2}-1/32
\,{\pi}^{2}-1/4\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) 
$$

Comment: @Dr Sonnard Graubner  Thanks, I will check this answer. The expected answer is: $J=\frac{3\ln^2 2}{16}-\frac{\pi^2}{192}+\frac{1-\ln 2}{4}.$,

Comment: Substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and then do integration by parts, where you differentiate the logarithm. For the integration use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. You can simplify,try : `simplify(convert(int, polylog))`.

Comment: @Dr,SonnhardGraubner But the question is to do it by hand.

Comment: @thomasfemi But then $I$ integral re-appears. The idea is not to use the known value of $I$. in order to find $J$. For as guess  the known value of $I$ may be used as a hint (only).

Answer (score 2):

With $u=\tan(x)$ we get
$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac {\ln (1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^2+1} \frac{\ln(1+u)}{(1+u)^2}$$
Then Integration by parts, where we differentiate the logarithm
$$J=\ln(1+u)\frac{1}{4}\left(2\ln(1+u)-\frac{2}{u+1}-\ln(1+u^2)\right)|_0^1 +\\ \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1du \frac{1}{1+u}\left(\ln(1+u^2) +\frac{2}{u+1}-2\ln(1+u)\right) \\= \frac{\ln(2)}{4}(2\ln(2)-1-\ln(2))+\frac{1}{4}(I_1+I_2-I_3)$$

Here, $I_2$ and $I_3$ are very easy. Use $x=1+u$ for $I_2$ to obtain
$$I_2=1$$
And use integration by parts for $I_3$, where you differentiate the logarithm to get
$$I_3=2\ln(2)^2-I_3 \Rightarrow I_3=\ln(2)^2$$
The integral $I_1$ is tricky, but the solution is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013351/need-help-with-int-01-frac-ln1x21x-dx) to be 
$$I_1=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{48} + \frac{3}{4}\ln(2)^2$$

Combining everything we obtain
$$J=\frac{3\ln^2 2}{16}-\frac{\pi^2}{192}+\frac{1-\ln 2}{4}$$
as stated by you.

Edit: I noticed that the $I_1$ integral is too close to the integral $I$ that you forbid to use... Sorry about that.

Comment: Side Comment - I like that the exact value of $J$ is a quadratic in $\ln(2)$.