# How do I get this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is from a list of problems from a local university's Integration Bee.  I have no idea how to do it, but I thought maybe someone here can explain it to me.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx$$

The answer they have is $\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{8}$, but no clue how they got there.

Thanks!

Comment: Any attempts you have made so far?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate....

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-mathrm-dx

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched deeper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx\;,$$ Put $$x=\frac{1-t}{1+t} = -\left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)=\frac{2}{t+1}-1$$

So we get $$dx=-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt$$ and changing Limits ,We get

$$I = -\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+t}\right)}{2(1+t^2)}\cdot \frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\cdot (1+t)^2dt = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln 2-\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}dt$$

So we get $$I = \ln 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt-I \Rightarrow 2I = \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \ln 2$$

So we get $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{8}\cdot \ln 2$$