# $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$$
$u=x+1$ so $du=dx$
$$I=\int_1^2\frac{\ln(u)}{(u-1)^2+1}du$$
$v=\ln(u)$ so $du=udv$
$$I=\int_0^{\ln(2)}\frac{ve^v}{(e^v-1)^2+1}dv$$
$e^v-1=\tan(w)$ so $dv=\frac{\sec^2(w)dw}{e^v}$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/4}vdw=\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(\tan(w)+1)dw$$
However this does not seem to make the problem any easier, I was thinking about using Feynman's trick, letting:
$$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^a+1}dx$$
but this also seems to complicate things more.

I also thought of using a different new variable:
$$I(b)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^a}dx$$
$$I'(b)=\int_0^1-\frac{\ln^2(x+1)}{(x+1)^a}dx$$
but this had the opposite effect to what I'm looking for (eliminate the $\ln(x+1)$)

EDIT

The hint given is:
$$\tan(x\pm y)=\frac{\tan(x)\pm\tan(y)}{1-\mp\tan(x)\tan(y)}$$
and I see the potential link to $\arctan$ but not $\tan$

Comment: The question is just help on solving this integral

Comment: look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155941/515527 .This is a pretty known Putnam integral.

Comment: @Zacky nice some of those answers come out really neat, didn't think of that one