# Introduce a parameter to determine the value of $\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How could I introduce a parameter to determine the value of $\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$?

Comment: Do you mean to use what is commonly referred to as Feynman's trick, otherwise known as [Leibniz' rule for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Comment: This is the idea.

Comment: What did you try? You are not new here. Please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155954) answers your question. (Found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog(1%2Bx)%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7Ddx%24&p=1).)

Comment: I tried $F(t)=\int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-1} log(1+tx)dx$, and tried to calculate $F'(t)$. In order to do that, I need to reduce to simple fractions the integrand  $(1+x^2)^{-1}(1+tx)^{-1}x$, but I could not.

Comment: This comment should be an edit of your post, and should be more explicit: What stops you in decomposing $F'(t)=\frac x{(1+x^2)(1+tx)}$ into a sum of simple fractions? Anyway, the link in my previous comment solves all.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the integral as $$I(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+\alpha x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$ 
The target integral is the case $\alpha=1$, note that for $\alpha=0$ we find $I(0)=0$ which is going to be useful later. Now we want to differentiate $I(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$, so we write:
$$I'(\alpha)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}I(\alpha)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+\alpha x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\log(1+\alpha x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
We can bring inside the integral the partial differential because of the theorem of **Dominated Convergence**.
$$I'(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+\alpha x)}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{\alpha+x}{(a+x^2)(a+\alpha x)}-\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2+1)(1+(\alpha x))}\,dx$$
Integrating with respect of $x$ we obtain an expression that is in $\alpha$:  $$I'(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+1}-\frac{\log{2}}{2(\alpha^2+1)}$$
We now recover the original function by integrating this derivative:
$$I(\alpha)=\int \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+1}-\frac{\log{2}}{2(\alpha^2+1)}\,d\alpha=\frac{\pi}{8}\log{\alpha^2+1}-\frac{\log{2}\arctan(\alpha^2+1)}{2} +C$$
By chosing $\alpha = 0$ we recover that $C=0$ as well. 
We end up with:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=I(1)=\frac{\pi}{8}\log{2}-\frac{\log{2}\arctan(2)}{2}$$